# Sql server: internal workings

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-complexity

Some of these might make little sense, but:

1. Sql code interpreted or compiled (and to what)?
2. What are joins translated into - I mean into some loops or what?
3. Is algorithm complexity analysis applicable to a query, for example is it possible to write really bad select - exponential in time by number of rows selected? And if so how to analyze queries?

Comment: There are many books available on the workings of databases.  This is a good question, but not appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... quite general questions, so some very general answers

1) Sql code interpreted or compiled (and to what)?

SQL code is compiled in to execution plans.

2) What are joins translated into - I mean into some loops or what?

Depends on the join and the tables you're joining (as far as i know). SQL Server has some join primitives (hash join, nested loop join), depending on the objects involved in your sql code the query optimizer tries to choose the best option.

3) Not reallyIs algorithm complexity analysis applicable to a query, for example is it possible to write really bad select - exponential in time by number of rows selected? And if so how to analyze queries?

Not really sure, what you mean by that. But there are cases where you can do really bad things, for example using

```
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM Table ORDER BY col DESC
```

on a table without an index on col to find the lagest value for col instead of

```
SELECT MAX(col)  FROM Table
```

You should get your hands on some/all of the books from the SQL Server internals series. They are really excellent an cover many things in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

You'd get a lot of these answers by reading one of Itzik Ben-Gan's books. He covers these topics you mention in some detail.

http://tsql.solidq.com/books/index.htm